# How to get the string array of all keys from the dictionary and modify every string in the same way

Tags: c#, dictionary

Easy and simple (but not very nice) way is just to get the array of the keys and iterate it updating every string.

```
string[] mapKeys = myDictionary.Keys.ToArray();

    for (int i = 0; i < mapKeys.Length; i++)
        mapKeys [i] = mapKeys [i].Replace("substringToRemove", "");
```

But is there any way to do it in 1 line of code (e.g. using LINQ)?

Comment: This won't update the keys used in the dictionary, just the copy you made in the `ToArray` call. Is this what you want?

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
mapKeys = mapKeys.Select(o=>o.Replace("substringToRemove", string.Empty)).ToArray();
```

or from your myDictionary:

```
string[] mapKeys = myDictionary.Keys.Select(o=>o.Replace("substringToRemove", string.Empty)).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use below LINQ :

```
mapKeys = mapKeys.Select( s => s.Replace("substringToRemove",string.Empty)).ToArray();
```